# "else" giving invalid syntax output. Why?

Tags: python-3.x

```
a = 200
b = 33

if b > a:
    print("b is greater than a")
elif b == a:
    print("b is equals to a")
    else:
        print("b is lesser than a")
```

The error that i get is:

```
File "C:\Users\A***h\Desktop\Python\Starting_out.py", line 8
    else:
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

Comment: Untab the else part

Comment: Thankyou @AbhigyanJaiswal 
Why though?

Comment: Please note that Python documentation teaches proper syntax. Being new to the language is not an excuse to not read it thoroughly

Comment: @OneCricketeer That's for sure. But reading document is a hell of a challenge.

Comment: @Bhav And syntax errors are reasons to close the question and maybe leave a helpful comment about the simple fix. [help]

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yup! I just had a modification for the code. So added it too. :)

Comment: I agree being new to the language is not an excuse to not read it thoroughly. I will be sure to keep this in mind. Thanks @OneCricketeer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a clear syntax error.

Every time we use `if`, `elif` and `else` statements, they are needed to be at the same indentation level.

#### What is the error?

The indentation of your `else` statement doesn't match the `if` and `elif`.

#### Correction

Here is your code after the correction.

```
a = 200
b = 33

if b > a:
    print("b is greater than a")
elif b == a:
    print("b is equals to a")
else:
    print("b is lesser than a")
```

---

Tip: You should not leave this `b < a` situation on the `else` as there can be other situations too.

You should rather add another `elif` block for this:

```
a = 200
b = 33

if b > a:
    print("b is greater than a")
elif b == a:
    print("b is equals to a")
elif b < a:
    print("b is lesser than a")
else:
    pass
```

`else` will now do nothing as I have given `pass` which just does nothing and continues the code.

Thank You! :D

Comment: I really appreciate your explanation. @BhavyadeepYadav . Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Accept this answer then? ;) I shouldn't be asking it though. Sorry!

Comment: No. its ok. i will accept it ;D

Comment: Click on the check mark then xD